# Find the place, find the palace

Tags: riddle

A part of me was a mode of transportation in the past.
A part of me is the mode of transport in the present.
A part of me is an important place in two fictional novels.
A part of me has acted in the movie made on one of the novels (described above).
A part of me is active only in weekdays.

Join the parts and you will get two words that shall tell the place and the palace.

Hint

> You shall not pass

Comment: I thinked a lot about rot13(Gur fbat Jbaqreynaq sebz Pnenina Cnynpr), and now I can't get it out of my head, even if it only fits half of the riddle

Comment: Do you want me to add hint, I don't know after how long you should start giving hints

Comment: Can you add a hint ,please?

Comment: @rhsquared This was asked March 15th of this year, not March 2015.

Comment: @Christian my bad.

Comment: Shantanu, you could add a hint now. It's been almost 3 months since you've asked the question, and it's still unanswered.

Comment: Maybe the place is rot13(Xvatfcbeg, GA, orpnhfr gurer ner znal npgbef jvgu gur anzr Xvat naq fbzr cbegf ner bayl bcra ba jrrxqnlf.)

Comment: Any chance of a hint yet?

Comment: I know it's too late but I have the hint

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe I have the answer!

*A part of me was a mode of transportation in the past.*

> In the past an **OX** would have been a common way to transport your goods.

*A part of me is the mode of transport in the present.*

> A **FORD** is a modern-day motorcar.

*A part of me is an important place in two fictional novels.*

> The **SHIRE** is the homeland of the Hobbits in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* by JRR Tolkien.

*A part of me has acted in the movie made on one of the novels (described above).*

> Elijah **WOOD** played Frodo in the *LotR* movie series.

*A part of me is active only in weekdays.*

> The **STOCK** Exchange is typically only open on weekdays and closed on weekends and federal holidays.

Put it all together and you have the *place*:

> The town of **WOODSTOCK** in **OXFORDSHIRE**, UK.

As for the palace? It's not that big a place, so there's only one there! And it's:

> **[Blenheim Palace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blenheim_Palace)**, birthplace of former British PM Sir Winston Churchill!

Comment: out of curiosity, was it the hint that helped you, cause it's been unanswered for a long time, before I added a hint today

Comment: @ShantanuBopardikar The hint pinpointed the books and film for me, yes. But then the rest fell into place because I live within a relatively short radius of the answer, would you believe it! I've looked at this riddle before and never cracked it. Guess it all just fell into place today! :)